# Moving of scroll bar up and down hide records from hierarchical records tree from UI. gwt and extjs

Tags: javascript, java, extjs, gwt, treestore

I am using tree in treepanel and treestore to show hierarchical records on UI for one of my application. When I add some no of records vertical scroll bar is appear. I am still adding records. When I do scroll bar up and down some records are invisible and process of hiding records is continue when I am scrolling up and down. When I do check or uncheck any one of record which is visible now, tree is refresh and I am getting all records back. Which component is responsible for this? How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Can you give us an example, maybe a https://fiddle.sencha.com/#home ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with a grid and solved it by declaring:

```
bufferedRenderer: false
```

I.e.:

```
Ext.define('YourTree', {
   extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
   
   store: store,
   
   //other properties

   bufferedRenderer: false
});
```

Comment: Can you please suggest how we can add this in code?